# what does shared library .so.5 mean?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I have compile a shared library(libcurl). Finally I found it generated "libcurl.so.5".
".so" means a shared library. But what does the number 5 means?
How can I generate library without number 5? just like "libcurl.so"

Comment: Think of it as a version number.

Answer (score 5):

Most fundamentally, it's simply a version number.  If the version number increases from, say 5 to 6, then it's supposed to indicate that all previous programs that were linked against version 5 are binary-incompatible with version 6 and thus need to be recompiled.  For example, if a function was **removed** from version 6 then clearly any application that used it wouldn't work any longer, so it's clearly unsafe for the application to automatically switch to the newer library version.  Bug fixes to an existing function, on the other hand, wouldn't require that the application be recompiled or ported and thus it's safe to use the .5 version with dynamically loading even thought the application was compiled against "a previous version (which is, um, still 5)".

In practice it's a bit more messy, as different people use the version number in different ways (often increasing it when they really didn't need to).

The libtool project has a much more [strict, and helpful, guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html) about when you should update the library version number.

In the end, you **should not** generate a library without the version number.  It's a promise to your users about whether the library is binary compatible in the future or not.

Comment: But also there is normally a symlink from `.so` to `.so.$NEWESTVERSION` which is used when building programs that use the library. If this is missing, it's usually because you've installed a minimal package that doesn't include the stuff you need for building.

Comment: Good point: the -devel or equivalent package usually has a linked .so version for people linking to it.  That's not what should be used at run-time though.